# self hosting react js app with CI tools

Tags: reactjs, go, continuous-integration, webpack, web-hosting

I am planning to deploy my own website using continuous integration deployment tools and technology stack i will be going with are React Js + Redux + Golang. What is the best tooling for hosting this site ?

Comment: Since go doesn't need a webserver or any other tools to run a website (it just needs to be compiled and deployed), I'm not really sure what you are asking.

Comment: If I implement Go WebAPI along with React Js in front end and use webpack to bundle front end UI, in this case Webpack transpiles code and create one js file. So my question is, what is the best tooling available in market for hosting this site (React Js) ?